# How do audit changes to dir via symlink?

Tags: strace, auditd

Use of the [auditd](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) system to watch a directory via a symlink hardly triggers any logs. Here is the situation:

```
# pwd
/home/root/serverfault

# ls -l 
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:12 dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Sep  1 15:12 p -> dir

# auditctl -w /home/root/serverfault/p -p rwxa -k PX
```

I had the naive impression that anytime I would read/write a file inside the `/home/root/serverfault/p` directory, logs would appear in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. But they don't.

Also, there is no audit log if I do:

```
# echo hello > /home/root/serverfault/p/hello.txt
```

I did some experimentation using [strace](https://www.redhat.com/magazine/010aug05/features/strace/) to run `ls` on few directories and evaluated the outputs with the information in the `auditctl(8)` man page. One interesting line from `strace` output that makes me think that audit logs should have been generated is:

```
open("/home/root/serverfault/p/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

May be it did not because `open(2)` follows symlinks by default. Logs get generated only when running `ls` on the parent directory (`/home/root/serverfault` in our case) of the path (argument given to `-w` switch in `auditctl`) being watched.

I realize that `/home/root/serverfault/p` is not really a directory but a symlink. But weren't symlinks meant to be used such that they did not appear to exist? Overall, it seems that auditing directory changes via a symlink is not supposed to be done. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,

```
   -w path
          Insert  a  watch  for the file system object at path. You cannot
          insert a watch to the top level directory. This is prohibited by
          the kernel. Wildcards are not supported either and will generate
          a warning. The way that watches work is by  tracking  the  inode
          internally.
```

There are no *changes* happening to the inode of the symlink file, as that is merely a file that points elsewhere. Add the watch to the directory the symlink points to, instead, or experiment with `-F path` related options, though, again, there are no changes happening to the inode of the symlink.